# REST web services with Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, spring, rest

I have a requirement in which CRUD operations need to be exposed through REST web services with Spring and Hibernate. Presentation is through JSF. It would be of great help if I can get a sample code for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController {

     @Inject private FooService service;

     @RequestMapping("/create", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
     public void create(@Valid Foo foo) { .. }

     @RequestMapping("/retrieve", method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public String retrieve(@RequestParam String fooId { .. }

     //etc for POST and DELETE
}
```

(Sometimes people tend to skip the request method limitation, but it feels more RESTful that way)